# Xubuntu crashes on opening firefox and/or chrome

Tags: xubuntu, firefox, chromium, crash

This is a fresh installation of Xubuntu 16.04.
I installed only Chromium from the software center.

Issue is that as soon as I open either `chromium` or `firefox`, the OS freezes with the mouse and keyboard not responding, and the display freezes to the current screen. Then I have to power off manually and reboot every time (and I have to be careful not to open browser by mistake !).

How to **check the relevant logs** and resolve this issue.

System specs:

```
Intel i7 2600
20 Gb RAM
No additional GPU.
```

**Updates:**

I have disabled hardware acceleration in Chromium by starting it successfully with `chromium-browser --disable-gpu` in terminal. Then changed the settings under option. Chrome works now. But firefox, still crashing. I have tried reinstalling Firefox but problem persists.

Comment: Check `journalctl -xe` or `journalctl -xe | tail`

Comment: But ` journalctl`  has logs and messages of the current session. Since I have to reboot everytime, the previous log cannnot be seen with `journalctl`.

Comment: try: `dmesg -H | tail -20`

Comment: @ankit7540 Any solution found?

Comment: No solution yet. ( I just make sure not to open firefox !)